# Excel not exporting sheet when using Format(Now() function?

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason I am getting a Run-time error '1004' when I execute the following sub-routine:

```
Sub Export()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

MyFileName = "CSV_Export_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\SuperUser\Desktop\" & MyFileName
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Sub
```

But when I replace the MyfileName line with:

```
MyFileName = "CSV_Export_" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
```

Then it works and saves the sheet perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work, because in the Now() you have `:`. 
E.g. `CSV_Export_2017-05-08 15:19:07` and the `:` is not allowed as a symbol.

Something like this will get you around:

```
?replace("CSV_Export_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"),":","__")
CSV_Export_2017-05-08 15__22__54
```

Or even like this:

```
?"CSV_Export_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh_mm_ss")
CSV_Export_2017-05-08 15_25_13
```

Comment: Okay, so how do you get around it?

Comment: why not just `"CSV_Export_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh__mm__ss")` There's no need for the `Replace`

Comment: As suggested by @Vityata, replacing ":" with "_" is one way. Or changing the whole format will do, as long as there is no special characters.

Comment: @Porkball21 - to go one step further in your coding, feel free to use `Option Explicit` on top of the sub - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201705081327273706926

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the colon ":" on your first line is causing the issue.
We cannot save files that contains some of the special characters including colon.